# XCODE 5 deletes all cocoa pods related when discarding changes

Tags: ios, xcode5, cocoapods

In my XCode5 iOS application when I go to Source Control -> Discard All Changes... to revert to yesterday's commit. I now get a message `"Warning the File for the container that was at /Users.../myproject.xcworkspace has disappeared"`.  Do you want to re-save the container or close it?"  The button options are **"Close" and "Re-save"**.  Either choice now trashes my project.  The cocoa pod related files and folders are all deleted.  Fortunately I have backups, but it is disconcerting to have GIT destroy my project.

I've performed a "Discard all changes" previously and subsequent to installing cocoa pods, and didn't have it trash my project like this.  Any ideas?

I'm running an Mac Mini I7 with Mavericks and XCODE 5.

Comment: Does anyone have suggestions for how to restore my XCODE to work with GIT?  When I check folders and files to add to the commit (that will get deleted upon a discard all changes) I get a msg that it can't locate them.  I.e. GIT Commit is currently rendered worse than useless because files that are not committed get removed upon "discard all changes".

Comment: XCode does not handle changes to the project file well. Your project file seems to have moved, which may mean that the pathes are different now, which could lead to the project not finding any files anymore. You would have to repair all pathes, or repair the project file